# Chosing the container for a form

Tags: forms, webforms

I am currently programmatically constructing a form. For that, I used the `hook_form()` . My form is displayed and all its functionality are good.

The problem is that it is not displayed inside the `div` container as it normally should be. Anyone knows how to define, maybe as an attribute, the form in this tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `hook_form`:

```
$form['first_element'] = array(
  '#prefix' => '<div class="wrapper>',
  '#title' => t('First name'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#default_value' => '0',
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
$form['last_element'] = array(
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#title' => t('First name'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#default_value' => '0',
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
return $form
```

Comment: What if the tag already exists. For example, i have a region that have <div class="myclass"> blabla </div>. How can i tell the form to render inside this div ?

Comment: in template file for instance or block: ` $form = drupal_get_form("custom_form");
  print render($form);`